# Yousician on Ubuntu 16.04 requires OpenGL3.2

Tags: opengl

I need to have OpenGL3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 Lenovo B560 laptop to run Yousician but I can't find a way to upgrade to OpenGL 3.2. Current is

```
blades@laptop:~$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 17.3.0-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered I can't activate OpenGL 3.2 at this laptop because the gfx card won't support it.